# Display php table

Tags: php

I have a PHP code here. I don't know what's wrong with this, but the `total_sp` count is working, but the table will not display.

This table is working on other "if statement" using query with one implode.

This portion is working..

```
if (isset($_GET['Filter'])) {//////////////////////

                      if (!isset($_GET['program']) && !isset($_GET['year']) && !isset($_GET['stat'])) {
                                echo "<tr><td colspan='8'><font color='red' face='Courier New' size='5'><center><b>PLEASE SELECT ITEM</b></center></font></td></tr>";
                                $total_sp = 0;
                      }

                      if (isset($_GET['program'])) {

                          $prog = $_GET['program'];
                          $proglist = "'" . implode("','" , $prog) . "'";

                          $sql_query =  "SELECT * FROM lfpstatustable1 WHERE prov = 'Biliran' AND program IN ($proglist)";
                          $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query);
                          $total_sp = 0;
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                              echo "<tr href='view.php?id_num=",$row[0],"'><td width='10px' class='Program'>",$row[1],"</td>
                              <td width='10px' class='Year'>",$row[2],"</td>
                              <td width='20px' class='Province'>",$row[3],"</td>
                              <td width='20px' class='LGU'>",$row[4],"</td>
                              <td width='20px' class='Barangay'>",$row[5],"</td>
                              <td width='30px' class='Project'>",$row[6],"</td>
                              <td width='20px' class='Allocation'>",number_format($row[7]),"</td>
                              <td width='20px' class='Status'>",$row[9],"</td>
                              <td width='5px' >",round((float)$row[17] * 100, 2) . '%',"</td></tr>
                              ";

                              $sum_sp = $row[8];
                              $total_sp += $sum_sp;
                      }

                      if ($total_sp == 0) {
                        echo "<tr><td colspan='8'><font color='red' face='Courier New' size='5'><center><b>ITEM NOT FOUND</b></center></font></td></tr>";
                        $total_sp = 0;
                        }
                      }


                      if (isset($_GET['year'])) {

                          $year = $_GET['year'];
                          $yearlist = "'" . implode("','" , $year) . "'";

                          $sql_query =  "SELECT * FROM lfpstatustable1 WHERE prov = 'Biliran' AND proj_year IN ($yearlist)";
                          $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query);
                          $total_sp = 0;
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                              echo "<tr href='view.php?id_num=",$row[0],"'><td width='10px' class='Program'>",$row[1],"</td>
                              <td width='10px' class='Year'>",$row[2],"</td>
                              <td width='20px' class='Province'>",$row[3],"</td>
                              <td width='20px' class='LGU'>",$row[4],"</td>
                              <td width='20px' class='Barangay'>",$row[5],"</td>
                              <td width='30px' class='Project'>",$row[6],"</td>
                              <td width='20px' class='Allocation'>",number_format($row[7]),"</td>
                              <td width='20px' class='Status'>",$row[9],"</td>
                              <td width='5px' >",round((float)$row[17] * 100, 2) . '%',"</td></tr>
                              ";

                              $sum_sp = $row[8];
                              $total_sp += $sum_sp;
                      }

                      if ($total_sp == 0) {
                        echo "<tr><td colspan='8'><font color='red' face='Courier New' size='5'><center><b>ITEM NOT FOUND</b></center></font></td></tr>";
                        $total_sp = 0;
                        }
                      }


                      if (isset($_GET['stat'])) {

                          $stat = $_GET['stat'];
                          $statlist = "'" . implode("','" , $stat) . "'";

                          $sql_query =  "SELECT * FROM lfpstatustable1 WHERE prov = 'Biliran' AND status IN ($statlist)";
                          $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query);
                          $total_sp = 0;
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                              echo "<tr href='view.php?id_num=",$row[0],"'><td width='10px' class='Program'>",$row[1],"</td>
                              <td width='10px' class='Year'>",$row[2],"</td>
                              <td width='20px' class='Province'>",$row[3],"</td>
                              <td width='20px' class='LGU'>",$row[4],"</td>
                              <td width='20px' class='Barangay'>",$row[5],"</td>
                              <td width='30px' class='Project'>",$row[6],"</td>
                              <td width='20px' class='Allocation'>",number_format($row[7]),"</td>
                              <td width='20px' class='Status'>",$row[9],"</td>
                              <td width='5px' >",round((float)$row[17] * 100, 2) . '%',"</td></tr>
                              ";

                              $sum_sp = $row[8];
                              $total_sp += $sum_sp;
                      }

                      if ($total_sp == 0) {
                        echo "<tr><td colspan='8'><font color='red' face='Courier New' size='5'><center><b>ITEM NOT FOUND</b></center></font></td></tr>";
                        $total_sp = 0;
                        }
                      }
```

Until i am using two implode and the table is not working..

```
if (isset($_GET['program']) && isset($_GET['year'])) {

                          $prog = $_GET['program'];
                          $proglist = "'" . implode("','" , $prog) . "'";

                          $year = $_GET['year'];
                          $yearlist = "'" . implode("','" , $year) . "'";

                          $sql_query =  "SELECT * FROM lfpstatustable1 WHERE prov = 'Biliran' AND program IN ($proglist) AND proj_year IN ($yearlist)";
                          $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query);
                          $total_sp = 0;
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                              echo "<tr href='view.php?id_num=",$row[0],"'><td width='10px' class='Program'>",$row[1],"</td>
                              <td width='10px' class='Year'>",$row[2],"</td>
                              <td width='20px' class='Province'>",$row[3],"</td>
                              <td width='20px' class='LGU'>",$row[4],"</td>
                              <td width='20px' class='Barangay'>",$row[5],"</td>
                              <td width='30px' class='Project'>",$row[6],"</td>
                              <td width='20px' class='Allocation'>",number_format($row[7]),"</td>
                              <td width='20px' class='Status'>",$row[9],"</td>
                              <td width='5px' >",round((float)$row[17] * 100, 2) . '%',"</td></tr>
                              ";

                              $sum_sp = $row[8];
                              $total_sp += $sum_sp;
                      }

                      if ($total_sp == 0) {
                        echo "<tr><td colspan='8'><font color='red' face='Courier New' size='5'><center><b>ITEM NOT FOUND</b></center></font></td></tr>";
                        $total_sp = 0;
                        }
                      }

                    //////////////////////////////////////////////
                    }

                    ?>
```

Specifically this:

```
$sql_query =  "SELECT * FROM lfpstatustable1 WHERE prov = 'Biliran' AND program IN ($proglist) AND proj_year IN ($yearlist)";
```

Can I use two or more implode?

Comment: Check the page source of generated html from browser

Comment: Where are the `<table>` and `</table>` tags (the first should be before the `while` starts, and the other after the `while` loop ends)?  You have only output rows. But as @Arvind said, have a look at the browser page source.

Comment: Beware of SQL injections in your `$sql_query`...

Comment: Use dot(.) inplace of comma (,) like `",$row[4],"`

Comment: this table is working on other "if statement" using query with one implode, but this portion i am using two implode and the table is not working

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Yap, and i think the problem is in the implode function, but i cant solve it

Comment: There's a problem in the second implode, but i dont know why

Answer (score 1):

You are using this ',' instead of '.'

```
<td width='10px' class='Year'>",$row[2],"</td>
```

use this

```
 <td width='10px' class='Year'>".$row[2]."</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want concatenate or merge some strings and variables then use "." (dot).